# Magento 2 simple module not working on a particular system

Tags: magento2, extensions

I have just created a "HelloWord" module and I just tested it on many systems but its not working on a particular system with XAMPP (PHP 5.5, MySQL 5.6.24) and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running.
5.
Here is the package: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98186464/Amin.rar

What should I check or config in PHP or Apache or Ubuntu to get it work ? The strange thing is that Magento 2 is running and working in this particular systems but only my simple HelloWorld module is not working properly (it doesn't load the layout in /helloworld/index/index controller, and simply just shows the title "Amin Helloworld", but the layout is not loaded at all)

Comment: For future reference, you can look at our [Magento 2 samples repo](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout `app/code/Amin/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml`, `Amin\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld` changes to `Amin\HelloWorld\Block\Helloworld` (`Helloworld` has all lower-case letters). And try to rename the view folder `app/code/Amin/HelloWorld/view` to lower case also.

Remember that Magento loads the name of classes with case sensitivity. If we have some troubles when creating a simple module, please check our file structure, naming (including case sensitivity).

Comment: I have done that also and then hit this command: php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade but still don't see any difference in the output!

Comment: Try to rename the view folder `app/code/Amin/HelloWorld/view` to lower case also.